# Remove shipping address from paypal

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypal-rest-sdk (the version for python) and I have some issue with the shipping address. Simple it shouldn't be there as we sell service, not items. Is there any way to keep using the PayPal sdk and remove the shipping address?

Comment: Look for a parameter or something in the SDK for "noshipping".  I know the Classic API has that parameter, and if you set it to 1, or true, then no shipping info will be collected during the checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a feature request and it should be fixed in the next few months.
Here is the link with more information about it:

- https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/wiki/Existing-Issues-and-Unavailable%5CUpcoming-features
- https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/issues/57